# Connecting to SQL Server database using IP address in different networks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

As well, we can connect to a SQL Server database using IP address in the same network. But how do I connect to a SQL Server database using IP address in a different network?

For the example, I need to connect to a SQL Server database in office, home network.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague, but sounds like a firewall problem.

If you're trying to connect to a office SQL Server from a home network, it's probably behind a firewall.  You can talk to your network people, but unlikely that they'll open up a hole to the outside.

Also, if you specify the port in your connection string "sqlserver.domain.com,port" then it uses TCP/IP which can sometimes solve this issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm tired to connect it but showing handshake error in application.(192.168.1.1,1533).